# Reading a barcode with javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js, barcode, barcode-scanner

I have a barcode gun scanner reading, barcodes, of course, into input fields. At the moment, I am able to read the barcode but it is returning every digit separately. I need it as a whole string. I have been breaking my skull about this.

For example, I read a bottle of water's barcode, the input field catches the number correctly (i.e. 688267022760). When I console log it, I get independent instances for each digit.

[image]

My template (VueJS) triggers the scanner event on input. Which I am not entirely sure if that is the correct event. I tried keydown and keyup as well. Not exactly sure which is the recommended event listener for a scan gun. Anyway this is what I have in my template:

```
<input id="packageInput" type="text" @input="onBarcodeScanned" />
```

And in my script:

```
onBarcodeScanned(barcode) {
  let numbers = barcode.data; //data is the object property I need
  console.log(numbers); //this shows me values I need
  let newarr = []; //creating an emprty array where I assume I need to push data to

  // looping through the data and pushing it to the new array, which does not do what I want but it was my logic
  for (var i = 0; i < numbers; i++) {
    newarr.push(numbers);
  }
},
```

The desired effect would be to get those independent values in an array and then joined as a string.

P.S.

Reading the barcode property returns a series of objects with lots of handlers for several functions. The property of interest is `data`. See below an example of the barcode objects
[image]

How can I do this? I'm stumped

P.P.S
I understand the scanner itself comes with a series of instructions to program it. Some of which I don't understand too well. Perhaps there is a type of barcode that returns as a string instead of each digit as an object? The scanner I am using is a Wasp CCDScanner WCS3900

Comment: Hello, i'm struggling with the same issue. Have you ever found a solution?

Answer (score 1):

`onInput` runs every time the value changes. Most barcode scanners will simulate keypresses to enter the values they scan, so as far as your app is aware, each digit is a keypress that's changing the value and so it reports each as an input event. An input event's `data` property is just the part of the input that's changed -- so you're getting one at a time.

You need a way to determine when the input is finished, not whenever it happens. I believe most barcode scanners will simulate pressing ENTER or TAB after a full scan is complete, so that might be what you want to detect, not with an input event, but with a keypress or keyup event.

Comment: That is helpful. Thanks!

Comment: This may help, too: https://manualsbrain.com/en/manuals/1431653/?page=15 According to the manual for your specific scanner, you can use the barcodes on that page of the manual to set the "terminator" character. I'd suggest CR, which is Carriage Return (keycode 13, or Enter), but you can choose whichever you want. The point is that you know what the terminator character is and you can have your app check for that onkeyup.

Comment: I saw that in the manual. I added it and it registers an additional object at the end with value "Enter". But I'm still stumped as to how I can collect the other values. This "Enter" object doesn't have the values collected anywhere in the object. hmm